# Texmaker: source editor and embedded pdf viewer on same window

Tags: texmaker

How do I get Texmaker to display the source and ouput in the same window, as advertised. This seems to be the default behavior on some systems, but not on others.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Fifth option from bottom in the preferences panel.

[image]

This version can undock the viewer (untick embed), which may not be present (or possibly moved) in some versions. the version shown is 3.0.2.

Comment: @jahee Where exactly is this checkbox? I may be temporarily blind, but I can't find it.

Comment: I updated this with a screenshot from my own PC. I pinched the original picture from the TeXmaker site. I can only conclude that the embed option has been moved or the option has moved to the `View` menu.

Comment: Or, of course, they may not have updated that image.

Comment: Oops, forgot to add the @TorbjørnT.

Comment: Actually, the problem was that I hadn't updated TeXmaker in a while, and before version 3.0.1 you had to have a horizontal resolution on your screen of 1400 pixels or more (see [changelog](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/log.html)). As my screen has less, the option wasn't available until I updated.

Comment: Interestingly, I need the other way around. It helps. +1

Comment: For the record, there are different ways of accessing this settings panel. See [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/247917/17423) for more information.

Comment: In Mac OS X you can open this panel with cmd+,

Comment: Windows 10, worked for me :)

Answer (score 3):

I just downloaded Texmaker 5.0.4. In this version you go to Options --> Configure Texmaker --> Commands (Was automatically selected for me) --> Pdf-viewer section. There you tick the box for "Built-in Viewer" and the box for "Embed". That solved it for me.