# Source and PDF side by side in Texmaker?

Tags: pdf, texmaker, viewers, live-preview

I've just started using Texmaker and am using it on a fairly large screen, large enough that it would be useful for me to be able to type my document and have the output PDF file next to it. I know it's possible as the setups at my university do exactly that. However, when I click the arrow next to "build pdf" it opens the PDF in a separate window. I've found a similar question on here to what I'm asking, but it refers to a preferences window that I simple cannot find anywhere.

Any help would be appreciated.

[Texmaker: source editor and embedded pdf viewer on same window](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36100/texmaker-source-editor-and-embedded-pdf-viewer-on-same-window)

Comment: My guess would be Edit > Preferences or Tools > Preferences or something like that.

Comment: There isn't a preferences option under edit/ tools/ view or otherwise.

Comment: From [the texmaker documentation](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/doc.html#SECTION01) you can configure texmaker "via the "Configure Texmaker" command in the "Options" menu ("Preferences" under macosx)." So I think, depending on the OS you have, the window you're looking for can be named differently. On Mac, you can access it by clicking on "Texmaker" on the top bar right to the apple logo then "Preference". On Windows there is a menu called "Options" (maybe it's the same for Linux).

Comment: How I didn't see that, I don't know. The options menu exists on Windows and allows just this. Thank you.

Comment: Since the issue was resolved by simply finding the right dialog in Texmaker, I'm voting to close as a duplicate of the linked question. That said, the current answer (describing where to find the dialog) is useful and should stand.

Comment: Useful discussion. I have benefited from it. Keep it up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I said in my comment, from the texmaker documentation you can configure texmaker "via the "Configure Texmaker" command in the "Options" menu ("Preferences" under macosx)." So I think, depending on the OS you have, the window you're looking for can be named differently. On Mac, you can access it by clicking on "Texmaker" on the top bar right to the apple logo then "Preference". On Windows there is a menu called "Options" (maybe it's the same for Linux).